# Qt: Default Parameters for function called by Signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qwidget, default-parameters

I receive this error when I try to connect a function with one default parameter and one non-default parameter to a QSlider:

```
230: error: static assertion failed: The slot requires more arguments than the signal provides.
         Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(int(SignalType::ArgumentCount) >= int(SlotType::ArgumentCount),
         ^
```

Does this mean a QWidget connected to a function cannot support default parameters? Is there a way to fix this?

Here is what I attempted:

```
void MainWindow::connections() {
    connect(sliderA, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, &MainWindow::someSliderChanged);
    connect(sliderB, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, &MainWindow::someSliderChanged);
}

void MainWindow::someSliderChanged(int position, char state = 0) {
    QObject* sender = QObject::sender();
    if (sender == sliderA || state == 1) {
        thing1->setValue(position);
    } else if (sender == sliderB || state == 2) {
        thing2->setValue(position);
    }
}

void MainWindow::default() {
    someSliderChanged(50, 1)
    someSliderChanged(70, 2)
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but you could make a second slot with a single parameter, which in turn calls your original slot. If you like I bet you could make the second slot a lambda.

Comment: You could also consider struct SliderConfiguration { int position; char state; }, and then have the slot as someSliderChanged(SliderConfiguration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean a QWidget connected to a function cannot support default parameters?

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) of signal and slots:

> The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot.

Therefore I would say that no, it is not possible.

> Is there a way to fix this?

As an example, if you compiler support C++11, you can use a lambda function.
Something like this:

```
connect(sliderA, &QSlider::valueChanged, [this](int pos){ someSliderChanged(pos); });
```

Otherwise, define a (let me say) *forward slot* that has not the extra parameter and bind it to the signal.

See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) for the overloads of `QtObject::connect` for further details.

Comment: Though I am running C++11, and your `connect()` solution does compile, `someSliderChanged` does not recognize the `sender` of the signal, thus it doesn't update, rendering this solution not quite working as I need it.